# LANフラットケーブルのラベリング

Tags: network

ラックサーバのLANフラットケーブルのラベリングをやることになったんですが
みなさんどうしてますか？

- 直接書き込む？
- 丸型ケーブル用のラベルを巻く
  　（実際やってみましたが当然うまく巻けません）

プログラムではなくNWの質問で申し訳ないですが
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://jubei.jp/dt/B0789BQB7C/　のようなラベルが便利そうに思います。実際に使ったことはないので、回答ではなくコメントに書かせてもらいました。

Comment: 食パンのタグ（バッグクロージャというらしい）を再利用すると安価（っつかタダ）という話も聞いたことがあります。フラットケーブル向きかどうかは微妙かも。

Answer (score 4):

ラベル付けをする目的に関しては、ファイバータグが使えると思います。
https://www.sanwa.co.jp/product/syohin.asp?code=CA-TAG111

ラックマウントサーバーのケーブルは、物理的な損傷を防ぐために丈夫なモノをお勧めしたいです。
ケーブルの自重で破損しないよう、[ケーブルフィンガー](http://www.lan-cabling.com/point1/4.html)等で横に流すこともご検討ください。

Answer (score 2):

フラットケーブルならビニールテープを90度の角度で挟み込む様に付けて、旗の様に余らせた部分にマジックでラベリングするのがコストが低くて、ズレないので良いかと思います。注意点としては糊が経年劣化でベトベトにならないものを選ぶか、定期的に交換するのがよろしいかと。
接続先で色を変え、大雑把な接続先が色で識別出来る様にするのもいいですね。